# Translate geo coordinates to address C# or jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, c#-4.0, geolocation, bing-maps

In my jQuery code I can get user Geo coordinates.
Now how can I translate GEO coordinates to an address either using C# or jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using jQuery. Give Lat, Lng in text box and click GO.

**UPDATED**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA7IZt-36CgqSGDFK8pChUdQXFyKIhpMBY&sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var map;
        var geocoder;
        var marker;
        var latlng;
        var infowindow;

        $(document).ready(function() {

        });

        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                //center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.4230, 98.7372),   // Coimbatore = (11.0168445, 76.9558321)
                zoom: 3,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var latlngStr = $('#address').val().split(",");
            var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
            var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);

            $('#latitude').val(lat);
            $('#longitude').val(lng);

            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                draggable: true
            });
            map.setCenter(latlng);

            geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function(results, status) {
                infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                $('#txtAddress').val(results[0].formatted_address);
            });
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <label>
        Lat, Lng:
    </label>
    <input id="address" type="text" placeholder="10.9435131, 76.9383790" />
    <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="initialize()" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 10px; height: 10px; display: none;">
    </div>
    <label>
        Latitude:
    </label>
    <input id="latitude" type="text" />
    <br />
    <label>
        Longitude:
    </label>
    <input id="longitude" type="text" />
    <label>
        Address:
    </label>
    <textarea rows="3" cols="30" id="txtAddress">
    </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Im looking for address instead showing it on map. If you check this website http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/find-address-from-latitude-and-longitude/#.UaMWAtKW_Sc when we insert GEO coordinates, on right side it shows the address of it.

Comment: Sorry i forget to add one thing. **Click on the Marker to view address.**

Comment: Its great! is there a way I can get the address directly to the text area instead by clicking on marker?

Comment: @Venka Yeluri  so u dont want map to view location?

Comment: infact I dont need a map, I need show only address using GEO coords

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

What you are trying to achieve is called [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse).

Explanation: [Google's usage limitations](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits) specifically mention that they forbid the users from using the Geocoding API without displaying the result on the map.

Although there are no instructions as to where the map should be located on the page, and which requirements should it meet, the intention is quite obvious.

There are several alternative Geocoding engines.
Try these:

[Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/export/reverse-geocoding.html)

[Bing maps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff859477.aspx)

[Yahoo maps](http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/)